# Как сократить код PHP?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Вопрос новичка. Понимаю, что он может быть банальным, но всё же. Как можно сократить данный код PHP?

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['name']) and !empty($_POST['phone'])){
        $name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
        $phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['phone'])); 
        mail('yourmail@yourdomain.com', 'Письмо с адрес_вашего_сайта '.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 
        'Вам написал: '.$name.'<br />Его номер: '.$phone,"Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8");
        $success = 'Сообщение отправлено';
        echo json_encode(array ('success' => $success));
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Вот если честно, то никакого смысла не вижу сокращать 8 строчек кода

Comment: А зачем? Тут, скорее, наоборот надо.

Comment: Наш senior сказал, что много дублирования кода здесь. Вот и встал вопрос, как сделать проще

Comment: Не по Вашему вопросу, при этом возможно для Вас такой подход будет более удобным. Как насчёт отказаться от конструкции !empty($_POST['name']) в пользу isset($_POST['name']) ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, сейчас уже не помню почему, но было нужно именно  !empty($_POST['name'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы так переписал

```
function GetPostVar($name) {
  if (isset($_POST[$name])
    return trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
  return ''
}

$name = GetPostVar('name');
$phone = GetPostVar('phone');

if(!empty($name) and !empty($phone)) {
  mail(
    'yourmail@yourdomain.com',
    'Письмо с адрес_вашего_сайта ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 
    'Вам написал: '.$name.'<br />Его номер: '.$phone,"Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8"
  );
  $success = 'Сообщение отправлено';
  echo json_encode(array ('success' => $success));
}
```

---

В чем отличие от исходного кода?

1. Вся логика чтения параметра из массива `$_POST` вынесена в одну функцию. Что позволяет в дальнейшем изменять эту логику в одном месте. Например, вы решите, что `strip_tags` лишнее. Тогда вы уберете эту функцию только в одном месте, а не в каждом чтении параметра
2. Проверка `!empty()` делается не для исходного значения, а для значения, возвращенного функцией `GetPostVar()`. Таким образом исходная проверка для поля состоящего из одних пробелов не сработает, а моя сработает

Comment: `GetPostVar` можно переделать под тернарный оператор)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie реализацию можно и переделать. Но саму функцию я бы оставил. Чтобы логика преобразований была в одном месте

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. Но объясните, пожалуйста, в чём его плюсы по сравнению с кодом из топика?

Comment: @Him Расширил ответ

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, спасибо за разъяснение.